# Xamarin.forms event on leaving/changing the page

Tags: c#, xamarin, events, xamarin.forms, page-lifecycle

I'm looking for something like a function

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
}
```

in Xamarin Forms. The problem is that this feature is called even when I turn off the phone display. I'm looking for a feature that only responds to the event when the page is changed - for example, the user in the menu clicks on a page other than the one that is being visited.

thanks for your advice

Answer (score 5):

You will need to combine `OnBackButtonPressed` and `OnDisappearing`

**OR** `OnAppearing` and `OnDisappearing`

You can create a `base` page which implement `OnBackButtonPressed` and or `OnDisappearing` and or `OnAppearing`.

And you save "Active" page reference in a static variable.

```
// this condition can help you concerning the screen on or off
if(this.Title == Activepage.Title) // or id
    return;
```

Answer (score 0):

What MVVM framework are you using? There are typically events built into the viewmodel that you can leverage.

If you want the page to do something specific on a button press then I'd suggest putting the code in there.